# mysql dropdown list when selected

Tags: php, mysql

[image]I have a table with this structure and trying to use a dropdown to select a language from the list and then display the contents of respective language_id .. I am using mysql and php 5.4

My code  is as follows, got stuck with looping and not sure how to get it

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT lang_id, lang_desc FROM languages ");

                                if(mysql_num_rows($sql))
                                {
                                    $select= '<select lang_desc="select">';

                                    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                                    {
                                        $select.='<option value="'.$rows['lang_id'].'">'.$rows['lang_desc'].'</option>';
                                    }
}
                                    $select.='</select>';
                                    echo $select ;  

                                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contents LEFT JOIN languages ON contents.lang_id = languages.lang_id  WHERE contents.page_name = 'index' AND contents.lang_id =  '$select'");
                                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

                                     }
```

Please help

Comment: Please give us a _proper_ problem description. _“got stuck with looping and not sure how to get it”_ is _not_ one.

Comment: `WHERE contents.page_name = 'index' AND contents.lang_id =  '$select'"` - trying to compare the lang_id column value with the _HTML code_ you just created probably doesn’t make much sense.

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this want minimum 2 PHP pages 1st for show data and 2nd for creat data in hear I didn't create DB connection please add it 
in 1st I use jquery for getting data from 2nd PHP
**show.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="lang" onchange="setlang(this.value)">
<?PHP 
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT lang_id, lang_desc FROM languages");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sqL,MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    echo '<option value="'.$rows['lang_id'].'">'.$rows['lang_desc'].'</option>'

}
?>
</select>
<div id='dis'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      setlang($('#lang').val());
    });
    function setlang(val) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "data.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:{val:val},
            success: function(result){
                $("#dis").html(result);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**data.php**

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contents LEFT JOIN languages ON contents.lang_id = languages.lang_id  WHERE contents.page_name = 'index' AND contents.lang_id =  '".$_POST['val']."'");
$data="";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $data.="your row data for dis";
    //
}
echo $data;

?>
```